# how to check if a day of hour is filled by the user?

Tags: android

I have 2 dialogs datepicker and time picker that turn one after another , so i am trying to make case to check if a timepicker is set or it's pressed cancel and only the date picker is set because i need it for later to set an alarm...i will use the same to check if the date is picked also...

//so here is what i have in mind

```
 public void funk2()
{       
    if(mCalendar.isSet(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))
    {

    Toast.makeText(dodadi.this,"Успешно е внесено2z! ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(mData.getText().toString().equals("SetAlarm")){}
    else{
    mData.setText(mData.getText()+" "+timeForButton);
    if(timeForButton!=null){n=timeForButton;}}



int m=mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    if(n!=null)
    {
        if(m!=0)
        {

    Toast.makeText(dodadi.this,"Успешно е внесено2z! ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

try like this to check a string not an integer, so first check if the time is null that u want to put in the calendar than set it as n variable

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html
take a look at paragraph 6 (onTimeSet)